# Submitting an application in multiple language in AppStore

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, app-store, itunes

I have developed a store app in cocos2d which has sound, text and images.
I have already submitted the English version of the application on appStore. Now I want to submit the same application in different languages (5-6 language). I can't do it in one application, as it increases my application size too large, due to sound(specially) and images for the different languages.

Can I submit it on appstore targeting audience of the country for which application is made like Chinese, German etc.

Note: Same application, only in different languages

Comment: careful, this may be in violation to app store guidelines: 
2.11: Apps that duplicate apps already in the App Store may be rejected, ... Check if you can find any existing apps that have duplicates that only differ in language. If few/none such apps exist it may be an indication that Apple won't allow this.

Comment: i want to submit my own app in different language. My problem is my application already of size 25 mb and if i add 5-6 more language it will increase to 70-80 mb so i decide to submit separately as there are mp3 sounds.

Comment: if you had looked at the link of the tutorial which I have put down here you would realized that the solution its there. therefore geolocalize every single file for the language that you are interested in, overwriting the original

Comment: I assume you have text as images that needs to be localized, and voice overs in mp3 files. You could try resampling the mp3 files, often you can shave off a lot of megabytes from mp3s without noticably reducing audio quality. And if you haven't already, change textures to .pvr.ccz and reduce bit depth as much as possible (even 16 bit cuts size in half). See my article here: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/

Comment: LearnCocos2D : I have use .pvr.ccz and image and text is not my problem. My problem is sound mp3 files and we are going to target 5-6 labguages which really increases the size

Answer (score 0):

You should check this 2 links, hope they can help you

**Ray Wenderlich Tutorial:** [how to localize an iphone app tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial), here its shown how to localize texts + images and i guess you can do it for sounds too

**Mac Docs:** [internationalization](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)